# Repeating key event generated when window focus changes

Tags: fedora, gnome, keyboard, wayland

Since I upgraded to Fedora 38, I have a strange bug with (I suppose) wayland. Basically if I change the currently focused windows through any mean (keyboard shortcut, mouse with focus on hover), an infinite amount of KeyPress and KeyRelease events are generated until I type some other key like Escape.

I have created a small GIF to illustrate the issue using `xev` but this happen with any software (Thunderbird, Firefox, QtCreator, ...):

[image: xev key event repeat issue]

To describe a little more I have used mouse focus on hover and that is why you see me going in and out of the window. As you can see, as soon as the focus is given back to the `xev` window the `F2` key is repeatedly pressed and released until I hit the escape key at the end. Obviously I didn't touch the `F2` during this experiment.

I'm on gnome version 44.5 using the Wayland windowing system and Linux kernel version 6.2.15 and in case this is relevant my laptop is a Lenovo ThinkPad E15 Gen 4.

Any help on this would be appreciated.

Comment: Is this causing any problems though? Can you tell us what?

Comment: Yeah, it is causing problems e.g. with Thunderbird it will try to rename the currently selected folder every time you focus on it. And this also happen with any other software that has a rename functionality bind to `F2`.